# Accessing single point data from time-series raster

Tags: python, raster, gdal, time-series, dash

I am creating a python dash app that needs to extract a single lat-long point of data from a each raster in a time series set of about 80000 bands, each covering the world. The raster data is stored across a few files. I can access the raw data as netcdf, grib or GeoTIF. The data is currently chunked so that each point in time is a chunk, as you'd expect, as that is more useful for most applications. However that makes it very slow for me.

The fastest option I have found is to use gdallocationinfo (~10 minutes), but I haven't been able to get this to run in the Linux server the app is hosted in, but this does work locally.

Data is downloaded from: https://cds.climate.copernicus.eu/cdsapp#!/dataset/reanalysis-era5-single-levels?tab=form

Other things I have tried:

- xarray/rioxarray/dask arrays - too slow with my current data structure (3+ hours), but I think if I could restructure the data, this would be the solution
- Converting to zarr - I don't have
  enough memory to rechunk the files into the orientation I need. In the current orientation, it is too slow (15+ hours). I could possibly do this if I broke the files down into smaller time steps
- Extracting each point using gdallocationinfo and saving as separate
  files - too slow (would take about 90 days)
- Downloading direct from cds api - too slow (takes about 3 hours)

Example code:

```
import xarray as xr
import rasterio as rio
from osgeo import gdal 
import os

ds = xr.open_dataset('path_to_file')
values = ds.sel(x=75, y=75).to_dataset().compute() # takes hours

ds = rioxarray.open_rasterio('path_to_file')
values= ds.sel(x=75, y=75, method="nearest").values # takes hours

values = os.popen("gdallocationinfo -valonly -wgs84 'path_to_file' 75 75").read() # takes 10 minutes
```

I believe the reason everything I've tried is too slow is because of the structure of the data, but there must be applications for which raster data needs to be accessed down the time dimension, so surely there is a newer method than gdallocationinfo, but for the life of me I haven't found it.